# Incoming Call UI is not showing up

Tags: calls, 8.0-oreo, background-process

When i get an incoming call, the ringer rings but the incoming call UI do not show up, instead the following notification is shown in the notification area:

[image: Notification].

So in order to answer the call i have to open the Phone app select the 'Return to call in progress' option, see the Screenshot:

[image: Phone App]

Fixed: Cleared the storage and cache of the Phone app. Now it is working fine.

Comment: [This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61808/dialer-screen-doesnt-come-up-when-making-or-receiving-calls?rq=1) might help you

Comment: @parthu_panther if the dialer app would have been disabled, it wouldn't run in background, would it? Couldn't that rather be some error with power management? Maybe the dialer app must be set up as "exception" to never be dealt with by power management. I vaguely remember there was something introduced with Marshmallow, called "Doze" ;) Sure one would expect the ROM cook had added the dialer to that exception list automatically – but that might have been forgotten here, maybe.

Comment: since the prob is fixed but assuming diff possible solutions with you has always been marvelous. @Izzy yes it wouldn't run in background when disabled but sure he can check to clear defaults and cache inorder to load factory settings of the app. And power management could be the real culprit. There are many battery optimization apps who sets exception for minimal battery usage. And ye cant guarantee about 'Doze' as it started with marshmallow and op's prob for oreo. Btw though doze is enabled, apps with high priority will notify always and system apps like dialer/phone has high priority.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, please post that as an answer, so the question is marked as answered. Don't edit the question to include the answer.

Comment: You should mark your question as answered as @DanHulme says. Otherwise, thanks for actually answering, because I came here with this problem, and clearing the app's "data" fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared the storage and cache of the Phone app. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when your hardware is finding it difficult to deliver an appropriate screen. Try rebooting and phone would be fine.

Comment: The hardware isn't delivering "an appropriate screen". What should that be? Any backing for that?